# How to integrate custom site with existing squarespace site

Tags: git, server, content-management-system, squarespace

I was hired to build a custom site for a client but was not told initially that what I made would be added to an existing square domain. I have done some research and none of the squarespace options I can find will allow me to migrate multiple complex, routed html/css/js files into the existing square domain. Does anyone have any experience doing something like this? Any good resources I can turn to?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can add custom code to an Squarespace website through some ways, most of them you will use built-in input spaces to customize syle with CSS or mintor changes in HTML. Most of these options are included in the free plans.

These ways of adding custom code to a squarespace site are listed on their official support page: [Adding custom code to your site](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815928)

But from what I know, for more freedom in developping, you would need to consult the [Squarespace Developer Platform FAQ](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545717). This is a platform that provides resources to customize the website other than with the built-in options, but this is a premium feature.